# Is it possible to display htp output using PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, oracle

Is there a way to display the `htp` output from a procedure using PHP?

**Executing a package function**

```
    $pdo = DB::getPdo();
    $result = null;
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare(
        "BEGIN
            :result := package_name.any_function(
                8495
            );
        END;"
    );

    $stmt->bindParam(':result', $result, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000);
    $stmt->execute();

    dd($result); //it works
```

But how do I get the data when the output is `htp`?

This is the procedure (It's an example) that I'm using.

**My Procedure:**

```
    procedure test(value in varchar2) is 
        begin
        htp.p('<p style="color: red;">test</p>');
        
        exception
          when others then
            htp.p(SQLErrM);      
    end test;
```

Answer (score 0):

Any environment can mimic a mod_plsql environment

1. Initialise the session

   declare
   nm owa.vc_arr;
   vl owa.vc_arr;
   begin
   nm(1) := 'REMOTE_ADDR';
   vl(1) := '1.2.3.4';    -- can be anything
   owa.init_cgi_env( nm.count, nm, vl );
   end;
2. Call your routine with htp calls
3. Prime the output in the dbms_output buffer

   exec owa_util.showpage;
4. Use dbms_output.read_line to bring this back into Python or any other tool

Answer (score 0):

Look at the section "Reusing Procedures Written for MOD_PLSQL" on p224 of Oracle's free [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html).

You can use `HTP.GET_LINE` in a wrapper PL/SQL block that PIPEs the HTP output or returns it as DBMS_OUTPUT.

For example, if you have a procedure that uses HTP like:

```
create or replace procedure myowa as
begin
  htp.htmlOpen;
  htp.headOpen;
  htp.title('Greeting Title');
  htp.headClose;
  htp.bodyOpen;
  htp.header(1, 'Salutation Heading');
  htp.p('Hello, world!');
  htp.bodyClose;
  htp.htmlClose;
end;
/
```

Then create a new function like:

```
create or replace function mymodplsql(proc varchar2) return modpsrow pipelined is
  param_val owa.vc_arr;
  line      varchar2(256);
  irows     integer;
begin
  owa.init_cgi_env(param_val);
  htp.init;
  execute immediate 'begin '||proc||'; end;';
  loop
    line := htp.get_line(irows);
    exit when line is null;
    pipe row (line);
  end loop;
return; 
end;
/
```

And call it from PHP using a query: `select * from table(mymodplsql('myowa'))`